# Local notification text change

Tags: swift, xcode, text, lockscreen, localnotification

So the question I have regards local notifications on the lock screen. The problem is that I want to ensure the user knows how to access options from the local notification (such as swiping left on the lock screen and down on the home screen). I figured that by saying "swipe down for more options" in the notification text itself this would do the trick however, it obviously will not work for the lock screen which you must swipe left to get more options. So my question is, is there a way to show different text for the lock screen and the home screen in a local notification? If not (which would not surprise me), does anyone have any other suggestions which I can use to ensure the user knows how to get options? Any help on the topic will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Once you display a notification, you can only dismiss it and present another one instead. However, you app does not get notified when the device is locked and unlocked.

This is also a terrible UX. On iOS 10, the way users see these options are different than swipe or pull (force press). Who knows how it will behave in iOS 11. Users are not idiots. They know how to operate their device.